# Qt debug error when running .exe

Tags: qt, runtime-error, qstring

I have written a game in c++ Qt, and I got a debug error message, when running the exe file. The error message appears only on one PC. It appears, when I try to display any text (`QLabel`, `QGraphicsTextItem`, anything). On other PC-s there is no error message.

The message is: `Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library`

```
Debug Error!
Program D:\gardener\Gardener.exe
Module: 5.0.2
File: global\qglobal.cpp
Line: 1977

ASSERT:"uint(i) < uint(size())" in file q:\qt5_workdir\w\s\qtbase\include\qtcore../../src/corelib/tools/qstring.h, line 729

Details:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: Gardener.exe
Application Version: 0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp: 51d6cba1
Fault Module Name: Qt5Cored.dll
Fault Module Version: 5.0.2.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 516366c9
Exception Code: 80000003
Exception Offset: 0005f1d1
OS Version: 6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.49
Locale ID: 1038
Additional Information 1:5861
Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
Additional Information 3: f3d5
Additional Information 4: f3d5be0cad2787556264647dc02181c3
```

I tried to google it, but no success. Does someone have any idea what the problem could be? Thanks!

Comment: Are machines both 32bit or 64bit? It looks like types have different lengths which makes one of them to crash.

Comment: Please post the line in your code that triggers this assertion.

Comment: Machines are both 64 bit, and I also tried on a 32 bit machine, it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

This assertion can be triggered when accessing a non-existent element in a QString. But without seeing your code and the line where this happens, I can't tell for sure whether that's your problem.

Comment: In the code there is just a simple textitem added to the scene, like that: scene.addText("something"); If I delete this line from my code, it works fine.